# Explanation of how this lambda expression in plain English?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I converted a query syntax Select example from MSDN into Lambda. It works, and I have written it myself but I can't get my head around the commented line below. I mean, I am **selecting** from **numbers** array, and yet it works fine and instead of **digits** shows **equivalent strings** . How does it match the two arrays?

```
  int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
  string[] strings = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
                       "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" }; 

  //Confusing line: **How would we represent this line below in plain english?**
  var result = numbers.Select(d => strings[d]);
  foreach (var d in result)

  {
   Console.WriteLine(d); 
  }
```

**Output:**

```
five 
four
one 
..rest of numbers follow
```

**Original MSDN Code in Query syntax:**

```
var result= 
        from n in numbers 
        select strings[n];       

    foreach (var s in strings) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(s); 
    }
```

Maybe explaining such a thing is a bit tricky, but I'm hoping someone has just the right words so it makes sense :)

Thank you

Comment: lambda syntax is just shorthand for looping. `d => ...` means `foreach d ...`

Comment: Why, in your second example, are you iterating over `strings` and not `result`?

Comment: @jbabey: You mean lambda syntax within the `.Select()` method.

Comment: @mao47 are there LINQ methods where the lambda doesn't mean loop?

Comment: @jbabey: I stand corrected, you mean lambda syntax within LINQ extension methods. But it is still not all lambda syntax, as your original comment suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `.Select()` as "create an IEnumerable of whatever comes after the `=>`."

As a foreach, it would look like:

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach(var d in numbers)
{
    result.Add(strings[d]);
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 3):

A humble attempt:

"For each number in the list called `numbers`, take the string in the corresponding position from the list of strings called `strings`."

Answer (score 3):

> I am selecting from numbers array, and yet it works fine and instead
>   of digits shows equivalent strings.

Its your Select clause which is selecting from your `strings` array at the index of `d`, where `d` is each number in the `int` array `numbers`

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason it seems strange is the data used as an example. This line:

```
var result = numbers.Select(d => strings[d]);
```

is simply taking the integers in numbers and using them to index strings, and put that in a new `IEnumerable` result. If you look closely at `strings`, you'll notice that:

```
strings[0] = "zero"
strings[1] = "one"
strings[2] = "two"
... and so on
```

So the `strings` array is really acting as a dictionary, allowing you to look up the string representation of a number by providing it as an `int`. That means when you index strings[d] in your query, you are taking the integer from `numbers` and translating that value into a string.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something along the lines of

> Go through each integer in the `numbers` array, select the element
>   at that integer position within the `strings` array, and place it in an IEnumerable collection.

Answer (score 1):

The two arrays have the same `Length` and the `LINQ` in fact does some loop through the `numbers`, passes in the `index` into the `strings` and returns the `strings[index]`.

The point is the `numbers` mustn't contain any element which is equal or greater than the `Length` of the `strings`